# Software to match each sentence with each other from two epub files of different language versions of the same book

Tags: text-processing, text-search, ebooks

I have two `.epub` files which are the same book, just in two different languages. Comparing the books, each sentence has an exact counterpart.

Now I want to merge the two `.epub` files into one "multi-lingual" copy, matching eacj sentence to display it next to its counter-part. I can use "full stops" as parameter for this operation. I just need some little software or any online web application or some piece of code or any method.

Do you know any software that can perform this or any method to make this process easier?

Comment: "Excel or any other text software"?!  Excel is ***not*** text software! Sorry, pet peeve; too many people in my office using Excel because it is the only thing they know. Want a text list? Use Excel. Draw a timing diagram? Use Excel (I @#$1 you not)! Last week, someone gave me a database schema – which he had saved as JPEG – and inserted as  the only content of an Excel spread sheet !!  </rant>

Comment: @Mawg If you have a hammer as the only tool, all problems seem to be nails #D I had the very same experience with Word documents, btw. // **user273448:** Maybe you could [edit] and revise your question slightly, and also include some more details? I assume you've got two language versions of the same book, and want to make a "bilingual version" of that – assuming that each sentence has an exact counter-part in the resp. other book. That might be how a computer does a translation. But in real life, it's often a bit different.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, each sentence has an exact counterpart. I can use "full stops" as parameter for this operation. I just need some little software or any online web application or some piece of code or any method.

Comment: @user273448 Now we get closer. Can you please [edit] your post and fill the last remaining gaps: What OS must such software work on (probably Windows, as you originally came up with MSExcel), and how much would you be willing to spend (if the solution is paid)? As you're asking for "method" as well: if a development library is acceptable, please include what programming language it must be for.

Comment: "each sentence has an exact counterpart" - is that guaranteed, or merely your assumption? "I can use 'full stops' as parameter for this operation" - what about questions and exclamations? What about "complex" punctuation like in direct speech?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Full stops was just an example. All punctuations marks are in the same positions in both books. I can fix small problems after separation is done. I'm gonna re-read all over again anyway if I can ever divide into two separate columns.

Comment: @user273448: The reason why I wondered is the issue that sometimes, what is a fullstop in one language becomes an exclamation mark in another. Likewise, the treatment of fullstops at the end of direct speech can vary between languages.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes I understand what you informed. The sentences or languages I work on here do not have these differences that you mentioned. So it will not be a problem.